# Forms authentication appends return url even though there is no return url

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms-authentication

I use forms authentication in web application. I have this in my config file. I use IIS 7

```
<forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" cookieless="UseCookies" protection="All" 
       name=".ASPXAUTH" timeout="60" requireSSL="false" slidingExpiration="true"  
   enableCrossAppRedirects="false" defaultUrl="~/Dashboard.aspx" />
```

When i enter my site's url in the address bar it redirects me to

`Account/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2f` instead of `Account/Login.aspx`

I don't know what the reason is , but when i use IIS 5.1 everything works fine.

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forms authentication redirection puts the source URL into the login.aspx request as a parameter so it can return the user the to the page they entered.  `%2f` = `/`, e.g. the root of your site.  If you had entered the `www.example.com/coolstuff.aspx` your `ReturnUrl` parameter would be '%2fcoolstuff.aspx'.

Nothing is wrong, that is how forms authentication is suppose to work.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to hide the URL in the browser address bar:

```js
<script>
    if (history.replaceState) {
        history.replaceState({}, document.title, '//' + location.host + location.pathname);
    }
</script>
```